# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Connecting to Local database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to connect to a local database on SQL Server 2008 R2, I've tried the following and nothing works:

```
./
servername/sqlexpress
localdb
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide details on it and full connection string you are using?

Comment: Most likely, what you mean by "local" is the SQL Server **Express** instance - correct? And by default, unless you've changed it, that instance is available as `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: You try to connect with the sql management studio and this fails? Are your ms sql services even running?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I notice in yours question is that, it is not `/` but `\`.

1. If you instance is express version then, you will connect `name\SQLEXPRESS`
2. If you instance is not express version than you could connect with `.` only.
3. Check you SQLServer service. Is it running?
4. If none of this is working, can you post the error message?